# Parsing an error string in Lua

Tags: error-handling, lua

Lets say I have the following error string:

> err = "/mnt/cd4/autorun.lua:43: 'end' expected (to close 'while' at line 1)
>   near '-eof-'"

How would I parse the file path, line number, and the error message separately from the string?

I have no prior experience in parsing Lua strings, so I thought asking here would be useful. I also tried finding a topic solving the same matter but I could not find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
err = "/mnt/cd4/autorun.lua:43: 'end' expected (to close 'while' at line 1) near '-eof-'"
local file, line, errmsg = err:match('^(.-):(%d+):(.+)')
print(file, line, errmsg)
```

The pattern says: capture starting at the end of the line (`^`) a shortest group of zero or more (`-`) of any symbol (`.`), followed by `:`, then a group of one or more digits (`%d+`), followed by `:`, and then a group of one of more symbols (`.+`). You can read [about patterns here](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html).

Comment: This pattern would be more correct as colon may appear inside error message: `'^(.-):(%d+):(.*)$'`

Comment: Egor, correct, although I haven't (yet) seen error messages that include `:%d+:`. Updated the answer.